# Lamp package is not turning on flashlight on after Lollipop even after giving permissions in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, camera, flashlight

I am making an app which use the camera as well as Flash. I have set the Permissions for Camera in Android Manifest file and Do the code for start Flash one button click but unable to On flash on Post Lollipop devices. It is working fine till lollipop devices. I have put a permission to access the camera but still not getting result. Please Help. I am Added the code which i have completed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lamp/lamp.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:permission/permission.dart';
import 'dart:io' show Platform;


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _hasFlash = false;
  bool _isOn = false;
  double _intensity = 1.0;
  String platform;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
    initplatform();

  }

  //its just for getting the platform version
  initplatform() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      platform = "IOS";
      print('is a IOS');
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      platform = "Android";
      print('is a Android');
      //requestAndroidPermissions();
    }
  }

  initPlatformState() async {
    bool hasFlash = await Lamp.hasLamp;
    print("Device has flash ? $hasFlash");
    setState(() { _hasFlash = hasFlash; });
  }

  checkAndroidCameraPermissions() {
    getCameraPermissionStatus();
  }

  getCameraPermissionStatus() async {
    var get = '';
    List<Permissions> permissions = await Permission.getPermissionsStatus([PermissionName.Camera,]);
    permissions.forEach((permission) {
      get += '${permission.permissionName}: ${permission.permissionStatus}';
      if (get != "PermissionName.Camera: PermissionStatus.allow") {
        requestCameraPermission();
      } else {
        //_turnFlash();
        Lamp.turnOn(intensity:1.0);

      }
    });
  }

  requestCameraPermission() async {
    final res = await Permission.requestPermissions([PermissionName.Camera]);
    res.forEach((permission) {
      String a = '${permission.permissionStatus}';
      setState(() {
        if (a == 'PermissionStatus.allow') {
          //RestartWidget.restartApp(context).
          //_turnFlash();
          Lamp.turnOn(intensity:1.0);
        }
        else {
          Permission.openSettings;
        }
      });

    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.pink),
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Lamp plugin example')),
        body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Device has flash: $_hasFlash\n Flash is on: $_isOn'),
                new Slider(value: _intensity, onChanged: _isOn ? _intensityChanged : null),
                new RaisedButton(onPressed: () async => await Lamp.flash(new Duration(seconds: 2)), child:  new Text("Flash for 2 seconds"))
              ]),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            child: new Icon(_isOn ? Icons.flash_off : Icons.flash_on),
            onPressed:()
            //Comment the if code if you want run it in lollipop device
            //for post lollipop device
            {              
              if (platform == 'Android') {
                  requestCameraPermission();
              }else{
                Lamp.turnOn(intensity:1.0);
              }
            }
            //for pre lollipop devi e
            //_turnFlash

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _turnFlash() async {
    _isOn ? Lamp.turnOff() : Lamp.turnOn(intensity: _intensity);
    var f = await Lamp.hasLamp;
    setState((){
      _hasFlash = f;
      _isOn = !_isOn;
    });
  }

  _intensityChanged(double intensity) {
    Lamp.turnOn(intensity : intensity);
    setState((){
      _intensity = intensity;
    });
  }

}
```

> Added below permission for Android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />  
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" /> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

> Plugin for Lamp and permission

```
lamp: ^0.0.6 permission: ^0.1.1
```

Comment: Did you get any exception log?

Comment: No, i am not getting any exception. can you please help me how to on/off the flash in Marshmallow and post devices?

Comment: flash on / off not working and getting error - Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 4 in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart
Note: D:\john\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\lamp-0.0.6\android\src\main\java\plugins\flutter\lamp\lamp\LampPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:58600/IamL1H5pEQs=/ws
I/flutter (27398): Device has flash ? true
V/BoostFramework(27398): BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@cc3969